# NullPointerException with WebFlux and Mockito in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-webflux

I'm writing Unit tests with WebFlux and Mockito, and as a result, I'm getting a NullPointerException. Here's my code:

Controller class

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;

ExcelService excelService = new ExcelService();

@GetMapping(path = "/products/excel", produces = APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getAllProductInExcel() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=star-products-%s.xlsx", dateTime));

    Flux<ProductData> pd = productRepository.findAll();

    Resource r = new ByteArrayResource(excelService.productsToExcel(pd).get().toByteArray());

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok().cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
            .headers(headers).body(r);

}
```

Here's a repository

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<ProductData, String> {

@Override
@Query(value = "{ lifecycleState: { $not: { $eq: inactive_state__c } } }")
Flux<ProductData> findAll();

@Query(value = "{ lifecycleState: { $not: { $eq: inactive_state__c } } }", fields = "{ 'productName' : 1 , 'epaRegNumber' : 1 }")
Flux<ProductDataDTO> returnOnlyIdAndName();
}
```

And here's a test that's failing with NPE

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ProductControllerTest {

@MockBean
MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
ProductRepository productRepository;

@MockBean
ExcelService excelService;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}
@Test
void should_get_products_in_Excel() throws Exception {
    ProductData productData = new ProductData();
    productData.setTimestamp(1L);
    productData.setProductId("id");
    productData.setProductName("name");
    productData.setRegistrationDetails(new ArrayList<>());
    productData.setEpaRegNumber("");
    productData.setLifecycleState("");

    Flux<ProductData> flux = Flux.just(productData);

    StepVerifier.create(flux)
            .expectNext(productData)
            .verifyComplete();

    when(productRepository.findAll())
            .thenReturn(flux);

    RequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .get("/products/excel")
            .headers(HttpHeaders.EMPTY)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
            .content(String.valueOf(flux));

    mockMvc.perform(builder)
            .andReturn().getResponse();

}
```

The test fails with the message `java.lang.NullPointerException` when it comes to the

```
when(productRepository.findAll())
            .thenReturn(flux);
```

In the debugging mode, `productRepository` is null. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: 1. Why do you `@MockBean` `MockMvc`? (2. Why ExcelService?;)

Comment: @xerx593 >> ExcelService is here because is needed for another test method that's not included here. `@MockBean MockMvc` is an error, thank you for pointing it out. I'm still unable to get rid of NPE, though.

Comment: (excelService is "private, unmanaged" object in controller..this won't work as a "mock bean") ..to the NPE: why there are no other (spring test) annotations except `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`? (`@MockBean` needs "at least" a `SpringRunner`)

Comment: Well I tried with `@WebMvcTest(controllers = ProductController.class)` but I'm getting `InitializationError` (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`)

Comment: ..ok,some "progress"/change :)

Comment: You were right, there was an annotation missing. I've added `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, and that solved the problem. I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` now at `.get("/products/excel")`, but that's unrelated to this thread. Thank you very much! Can you please add an answer instead of a comment, so I can accept it as an answer to my original post/question?